# Attempting to use cout to print a list of the objects contained in a vector and ordering comes out wrong

Tags: c++, io, operator-overloading

I have an album class which is designed to store and Artist Name (string), albumtitle (string) and a list of track objects (vector). I'm trying to overload the "<<" operator to enable stream-based output.

The relevant code is this:

```
std::ostream& Album::printTracks (std::ostream &out, std::vector<Track> &t)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for (i=0; i<t.size(); i++)
        out << " " << t.at(i);
     return out;
}
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, Album &a)
{
    out << "Artist name: " << a.artistName << "\n" <<
        "Album Title: " << a.albumTitle << "\n" <<
        "Tracks: " << a.printTracks(out,a.getTracks());
    return out;
}
```

Which should print, in this order:

- The Artist's name
- The Album Title
- The tracklist

Instead it prints this when I give it the test data:

- The tracklist
- The artist name
- The album title

"Tracks:" followed by a memory location.

```
Constructor for "Track Class" is:
Track::Track (std::string t, Duration* d)
    {
        title = t;
        duration = d;
    }
```

The code overloading "<<" in the "track" class is:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, Track &t)
    {
    out << "Title: " << t.title << "\n" <<
        "Duration: " << *t.duration << "\n";
    return out;
    }
```

And eventual code being used for output is:

```
Duration* d = new Duration(3,4,50); //creating duration objects for testing
Duration* d2 = new Duration(5,7,300);
Duration* d4 = new Duration(3,3,50);
Track t1 = Track("Test",d); //creating track objects
Track t2 = Track("Test2",d2);
Track t3 = Track("Test3",d4);
std::vector<Track> tracks; //forming tracks into vector
tracks.push_back(t1);
tracks.push_back(t2);
tracks.push_back(t3);
Album a = Album("Test Artist","Test Album",tracks); //create album object
cout << a << endl; // output album object
```

Was wondering why the ordering doesn't print as expected?

Comment: As a side note, you should take the things you're printing by const reference.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that recreates your error so that we can help you in a timely manner.

Comment: @Code-Guru That would mean giving a whole bunch of code, stored across 7 different files, that is irrelevant to the problem but is almost all needed in order to compile it correctly.

Comment: @TheGeneral Did you read the link I gave? 7 files of code which is mostly irrelevant to the current problem is NOT an SSCCE by definition.

Comment: @Code-Guru: Most of it is class definitions which are *needed* because this piece of code uses objects of those types. However, given that those class definitions have been tested and proven as *working* then reproducing them here would seem to only increase the amount of code included without really helping anyone solve the problem.

Comment: @TheGeneral, It's often a good strategy to take parts of your code - anything you can - away, or make anything you can simpler, little by little, until it works. If you're left with a small, complete program, you've got a good question. You can copy the original and go back any time.

Comment: @TheGeneral An SSCCE is NOT (usually) your original code. It is a separate program which recreates the same issue you have encountered and are asking about.

Comment: @chris: If I take out: "out << a.printTracks(out,a.getTracks());" then it works perfectly.

Comment: @Code-Guru: Seemed like overkill for a simple question such as this.

Comment: @Code-Guru, To be fair, the code samples given were short and completely relevant enough that they provided all of the information needed to answer the question. But yes, I agree that an sscce is almost always a good asset for asking questions, and yes, formulating one sometimes solves your problem.

Comment: @chris From my experience asking my own questions here, your last point is the most important.

Comment: @Code-Guru, Indeed, I have solved several of my own that I was planning to ask by making one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's unspecified what order your arguments will be evaluated in. One of them has side effects (printing the tracks), so if it's evaluated first, you'll see those printed first.

Comment: What would be the method of specifying the order?

Comment: @TheGeneral, Print the tracks in a separate output statement after the first.

Comment: @TheGeneral: `... "Tracks: "; a.printTracks(out, a.getTracks()); ...` is one way.

Comment: I think it is better if you make printtracks into a `operator<<` and call it as `<<a.getTracks()`

Comment: @JonPurdy: Thanks, that seems to work. It's still printing out a memory register afterwards, though....

Comment: @KarthikT: This is a fair point, will have a look at doing that.

Comment: @TheGeneral, By `*t.duration`, did you typo `&t.duration`? Either way, it should most likely be `t.duration`. If it's printing out something like `0x401568FC`, that's a memory address. To avoid confusion, I'd stick with address over register.

Comment: @chris: The intention of putting *t.duration was to get the actual data rather than just the memory address, removing it results in each output line showing me a memory address instead of the duration data.
I'll post the constructor for the Track class above, if that helps.
The address looks like this: 6DD3C3E8

Comment: @TheGeneral, Then you must make sure that whatever you pass into the class lives long enough, since you copy the pointer in the constructor, not the object. Also, I presume `Duration`'s `operator<<` works?

Comment: @chris: hmm, OK. It should be living long enough as I am passing a pointer to a duration object when I create the new test; Will post the code above.
Yes,t he 'Duration's 'operator<<' correctly outputs the information when parsed a 'Duration' object.

Comment: @TheGeneral, Since you have a vector of tracks, it's possible if you deallocate `duration` in the destructor that you could be corrupting them due to the rule of three.

Comment: @chris: I don't.
Must admit, this is really wierd. There are only three items in the track list, so it shouldn't be printing out anything else.